# JQuery slidedown alert message disables submit button

Tags: jquery, button, bootstrap-4, slidedown, prop

I created a Jquery slidedown alert message that for some reason disables the Submit Button as soon as it appears.

[image]

My jQuery code is working perfect until the slidedown message appears: 
https://jsfiddle.net/godsnake/t0cswbpo/141/

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

      var limit = 3;
      $("li").on("click", "a", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        if($("a.active").length >= limit) {
          $("#message").slideDown();
          if($(this).hasClass("active"))
          {
          $(this).toggleClass("active");
           $("#message").slideUp();
          }

        }else{
         $("#message").slideUp();
         $(this).toggleClass("active");
        }
      });

    });

     $(document).ready(function(){


      $('li:not(.active)').on("click", "a", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        if($('li:not(.active)'))

        {

         $('#register').prop('disabled', true);

          if($(this).hasClass("active"))
          {
          $('li').toggleClass("active");
            $('#register').prop('disabled', false);      
          }

        }else{
        $('#register').prop('disabled', false); 
         $(this).toggleClass("active");
        }
      });

});
```

**CSS:**

```
#message{display:none; color:red; margin-top:-5px!important;}


li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="mt-3 container position-relative">



    <div class="m-0 p-0 mobiletitle sentence" id="message">Please only choose 3 options.</div>

    <div class="mt-2 mt-md-2 mt-lg-3 list-group d-inline-block text-left">
    <li> <a class="mb-3 btn btn-outline-primary sentence">Option 1</a> </li>        
    <li> <a class="mb-3 btn btn-outline-primary sentence">Option 2</a> </li>
    <li> <a class="mb-3 btn btn-outline-primary sentence">Option 3</a> </li>
            <li> <a class="mb-3 btn btn-outline-primary sentence">Option 4</a> </li>
    <li> <a class="mb-3 btn btn-outline-primary sentence">Option 5</a> </li>

            <li> <a class="mb-3 btn btn-outline-primary sentence">Option 6</a> </li>
                <li> <a class="mb-3 btn btn-outline-primary sentence">Option 7</a> </li>
                        <li> <a class="mb-3 btn btn-outline-primary sentence">Option 8</a> </li>
    </div>

        <input id="register" disabled class="border-0 font-weight-bold btn-secondary text-uppercase sentence py-3 btn-lg btn-block" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit Form"/>




            </div>
```

**What I'm trying to accomplish is the following:**

- Submit button should be disabled by default
- When the user selects at least one of the options the button becomes
  enabled
- If the user selects more than 3 options they are prevented from
  selecting any more options, and a JQuery slidedown alert message
  appear to let the user know that 3 options is the limit.
- Even if the alert message appears the users should still be able to CLICK on the Submit button as long as a 1 option is selected.

But as you see the problem start when the slide down message appears, the submit button becomes disabled. **Why is this happening to the submit button?**  Please explain with detail and better yet show me how is done, I'm a novice in jQuery and I'm pretty sure my jQuery code can not only be fixed but simplified. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would tend to rewrite your click handler squarely.

You used two diferent click handlers and got mixed up in the condition logic.
So on a `a` click, if the `li` doesn't have the `active` class, both handlers execute... That probably is why you have some unexepected behavior.

Additionnaly, the `active` class is applyed on both `li` and `a`... Which is useless.

Have a look at this more simple way to code the conditions in one single click handler:

*I used a `:disabled` CSS rule just to make the button's `disabled` state obvious.*

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  var limit = 3;
  $("li").on("click", "a", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    // Toggle the active class on the clicked element
    $(this).toggleClass("active");

    // How many active now?
    var active_length = $("a.active").length;

    // Condition to slide the message up or down
    if(active_length > limit) {
      $("#message").slideDown();
    }else{
      $("#message").slideUp();
    }

    // Condition to enable/disable the button
    if(active_length > 0 && active_length <= limit){
      $('#register').prop('disabled', false);
    }else{
      $('#register').prop('disabled', true);
    }

  });

});
```

```css
#message{display:none; color:red; margin-top:-5px!important;}


li {
  display: inline-block;
}

:disabled{
  color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<div class="mt-3 container position-relative">

  <div class="m-0 p-0 mobiletitle sentence" id="message">Please only choose 3 options.</div>

  <div class="mt-2 mt-md-2 mt-lg-3 list-group d-inline-block text-left">
    <li> <a class="mb-3 btn btn-outline-primary sentence">Option 1</a> </li>  
    <li> <a class="mb-3 btn btn-outline-primary sentence">Option 2</a> </li>
    <li> <a class="mb-3 btn btn-outline-primary sentence">Option 3</a> </li>
    <li> <a class="mb-3 btn btn-outline-primary sentence">Option 4</a> </li>
    <li> <a class="mb-3 btn btn-outline-primary sentence">Option 5</a> </li>

    <li> <a class="mb-3 btn btn-outline-primary sentence">Option 6</a> </li>
    <li> <a class="mb-3 btn btn-outline-primary sentence">Option 7</a> </li>
    <li> <a class="mb-3 btn btn-outline-primary sentence">Option 8</a> </li>
  </div>

  <input id="register" disabled class="border-0 font-weight-bold btn-secondary text-uppercase sentence py-3 btn-lg btn-block" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit Form"/>

</div>
```

[**JSFiddle** updated](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/4upxq61z/17/).

Comment: Yea, you rewrote it a lot more cleaner. I just slightly altered both scripts, but I didn't know enough to rewrite . I noticed that your script is different because it allows users to click more than 3 of the options, is it possible prevent them from clicking extra options after the 3?

Comment: Well... Yes more than 3 is allowed, but the message slides down, so he can un-click the one he wants... If the 4th click isn't allowed, what's the use for the message?

Comment: Or.. I mean... What will make the message slideup? A setTimeout could do... Is it something that would be ok?

Comment: Just say you have 100 of options, it might look neater if you tell users there's a limit and force them to unclick the selected option if they want to change it.

Comment: I made a second Fiddle, where I made it 100 options. An additionnal issue occurs in this context, since the "message" can be out of view. So I made it `position: fixed`... I played a little with it. It's not yet perfect... And can be optimized many ways, but it's a good starter for you. --- The 4th option is prevented. [Have a look](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/7rLgmj4n/35/).

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted and more! Props on improving on my design. I hope to one day be as talented as you at jQuery. Thanks for the help!